# Generate an associative array given two arrays?

Tags: php

i'm a lil newbie with php, someone can help me.
I want to generate an associative array given two arrays like:

```
$array1 = ["1","2"];
$array2 = ["option_1","option_2"];
```

Generated associative array:

```
$assoc_array = ["1"=>"option_1","2"=>"option_2"];
```

how i can do that?? thanks for ur help !

Answer (score 11, accepted):

use `array_combine()`:-

```
$array3 = array_combine($array1, $array2);
print_r($array3);
```

Comment: Thank you so much, works like a charm ! sorry for not read docs =/

Comment: @maudev welcome :) mark it  correct if its your solution..

Comment: @maudev  don't forget to mark and up-vote the answer. thanks.